# virtualkeyboard "Go" button changed to "Next" button when clicking on a node on vuejs-pwa

Tags: android, vue.js, input, progressive-web-apps, virtual-keyboard

I'm building pwa apps with vuejs...

One of them has a curious behavior since a short time https://scenaristeur.github.io/agent/

It seems that the "Go" button in the virtualKeyboard is changed to the "Next" button and I don't know how to catch a press on it with vuejs.

I think remember that three month ago it worked as expected, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT61BcjGfwc&t=35s : as far as i remember, this demo was ok on Android

Today I have this behavior https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQZsyVfPJjY at 00:47, I have a "GO" Button until I click on a node at 01:12, then I have the "Next" button on the virtual keyboard at 01:27.

[image: Go button]

[image: next button]

Clicking on a node opens a new form that allow the user to "edit" the node ... Is this that form that change the behavior of the virtual keyboard, changing the "go" button to the "next" button ? here is the code of the "editNode.vue" https://github.com/scenaristeur/agent/blob/atomix/src/views/NodeEdition.vue

I have tried to catch it with

```
   v-on:keydown.enter="onEnter"
    v-on:keydown.tab.prevent="onEnter"
```

but it does not seem to work

https://github.com/scenaristeur/agent/blob/cde744dfb9157922334f0c2a885c9fc150a0bd07/src/views/CommandInput.vue#L13

is there a way to always have a "Go" button on this "CommandInput" form?

I know I have change some code, but it seems to be the same on another project (https://scenaristeur.github.io/agents/) where I have not change the code and I had never seen this behavior before.

Could it be a Android system update that recently changed the behavior of the keyboard ? I'm on Android Samsung J5-2017 / ANdroid 9 / kernel 3.18.91-16642474

How could I change my code to always have a "Go" button for this input that I can catch with `v-on:keydown.enter="onEnter"` or how could I catch the "Next" button ?